# x:5, what is this statement?

Tags: python

What does the following statement do in python?

```py
x:5
```

Here the `x` is not even defined. The above statement runs without any error. Why does this work and what does it do?

I'm running the code on Python 3.8.3.

Comment: It's a type hint.

Comment: That's a poorly-formed *type annotation* for the variable `x`.  The thing to the right of the colon would properly be a type of some sort: `x: int` or `x: str` perhaps.  But Python itself doesn't verify the annotations, it just makes them available for external tools, so no error is generated here.

Comment: A bad and, if I may say, a useless type hint, but a type hint nevertheless. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0483/